# sessionStorage vs QueryString

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Suppose you have two pages (page A and page B).

In page B I have a save button which redirects to page A. I want to be able to pass data from page A to page B upon saving. (notice I'm using angular with aspx and be aware that these are two different pages and I'm not using angular routing but just a simple redirection between pages).

One way to accopmlish that would be using query string, for example :

```
http://mypage.aspx?data=2
```

Another way to accomplish that would be using sessionStorage of HTML 5, for example:

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem(data, 2);
```

Is there a prefered way to choose?

Is there anything different that goes on behind the scenes? Performance/security differences?

Comment: What is user manually changes the query-string-parameter ? User can change session-storage-value as well but chances are less...

Comment: you  can use sessionStorage if you do not want to pass the data using queryString.Its definately not visible to user using sessionStorage

Comment: the other way is using cookies or post method, but all these methods are visible/modifiable by the user if they're looking for it.